# Prove a limit of a function $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$

Tags: limits, functions

Let $ f: (0,  \infty ) \mapsto \mathbb{R} $  be defined by $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x} $

How can I prove that $ \lim_{x\to0}f(x) = -\infty $   ?

I tried to show that for all  $  z \in \mathbb{R} $
$ \exists   \epsilon  \gt 0  $ such that $ 0 \lt |x| \leq  \epsilon $,
then $  \frac{x-1}{x}  \leq z $.

How do I find such $ \epsilon $?

Comment: You can't because the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: The limit isn't $-\infty$. The function is unbounded, but whether it closes in on $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ depends on which side you come from.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that f is mapping from the interval (0,  \infty)

Answer (score 1):

Solve this inequality for $x$:
$$\frac{x-1}x\le z$$

Since $x>0$ you can multiply both sides by $x$:
$$x-1\le zx\iff x(1-z)\le 1$$

You can also assume that $z< 1$ and then
$$x\le\frac1{1-z}$$

So take
$$\epsilon=\frac1{1-z}$$